# how to select form elements under a <div> using jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms

There are form elements under a div, I do not know the type. It might be checkboxes or radios or select. how to select form elements without specifying the element type under a  using jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `:input` [selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/):

```
$(':input')
```

Which is basically short hand for:

```
$('input, select, textarea, button')
```

Answer (score 0):

In many case you want to select all form elements but exclude buttons , for that case use

```
$(":input[type!='submit'][type!='reset']")
```